# Detect if a jQuery UI dialog box is open

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using a jQuery UI dialog. If it is open, I want to do one thing. If it is closed, I want to do another.

My question is, how do I detect if a jQuery UI dialog box is open or not?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

If you read the [docs.](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-isOpen)

```
$('#mydialog').dialog('isOpen')
```

This method returns a Boolean (true or false), not a jQuery object.

Comment: How would you do this test for any and all dialogs? Say you have ten different dialogs with separate inits and options and you want to test if ANY of them are open, not a specific selector?

Comment: Add a class to said dialogs, then change the selector on your isOpen check.

Comment: plus also:  ten dialogs? maybe reducing that by re-using an instance or two is a thought worth considering

Comment: Also check if dialogue has even been initialized with `$("#mydialog").hasClass("ui-dialog-content")`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528706/how-can-i-tell-if-a-jquery-ui-dialog-query-has-been-initialized

Comment: it returns the object

Answer (score 56):

Actually, you have to explicitly compare it to true. If the dialog doesn't exist yet, it will not return false (as you would expect), it will return a DOM object.

```
if ($('#mydialog').dialog('isOpen') === true) {
    // true
} else {
    // false
}
```

Comment: Returns false in the latest JQuery.

Comment: How would you do this test for any and all dialogs? Say you have ten different dialogs with separate inits and options and you want to test if ANY of them are open, not a specific selector?

Comment: Maybe create a function like $(".ui-dialog").each(function(/*check this dialog*/))?

Answer (score 22):

If you want to check if the dialog's open on a particular element you can do this:

```
if ($('#elem').closest('.ui-dialog').is(':visible')) { 
  // do something
}
```

Or if you just want to check if the element itself is visible you can do:

```
if ($('#elem').is(':visible')) { 
  // do something
}
```

Or...

```
if ($('#elem:visible').length) { 
  // do something
}
```

Comment: I check my div if it not initialized like that: `$dialog.hasClass('ui-dialog-content')`

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get the above answers using "isOpen" to work for me, but this worked.

Answer (score 3):

Nick Craver's comment is the simplest to avoid the error that occurs if the dialog has not yet been defined:

```
if ($('#elem').is(':visible')) { 
  // do something
}
```

You should set visibility in your CSS first though, using simply:

```
#elem { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery dialog has an `isOpen` property that can be used to check if a jQuery dialog is open or not.

You can see example at this link:
http://www.codegateway.com/2012/02/detect-if-jquery-dialog-box-is-open.html