# How to disable focus if dialog is opened

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, focus

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(function(){
            $("#reg_id").focus();           
        }, 1000);
    </script>
```

how to disable focus if dialog is opened

```
setInterval(function(){
     if($("#dialogadd_participant").dialog("isOpen")){}
     else {
         $("#reg_id").focus();
     }
}, 1000);
```

isn't work, please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313784/detect-if-a-jquery-dialog-box-is-open/8181623#8181623

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.blur()` function to remove the focus, like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
     if($("#dialogadd_participant").dialog("isOpen")){
         $("#reg_id").blur();
     }
     else {
         $("#reg_id").focus();
     }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just shift focus from `#reg_id` to another object like `#dialogadd_participant` by calling either

```
 $(this).focus() // within the .dialog({...}) section
```

or

```
 $('#dialogadd_participant').focus() // after the model is opened
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign your setInterval function to a variable and then you can use clearInterval to stop focus.

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
        $("#reg_id").focus();           
    }, 1000);

 if($("#dialogadd_participant").dialog("isOpen")){
    clearInterval(interval);
    $("#reg_id").blur(); 
   }
 else {
     $("#reg_id").focus();
 }
```

I do not understand your actual reason why you are using `setInterval()` but using this `clearInterval()` you can clear calling `$("#reg_id").focus();` over and over again.